# FullCalendar slot duration starts with refresh

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar in my application. I have two views: 30 min and 2 hours.

The 30 min view slots always start with the time of last refresh whereas the 2 hours view starts with full hour.

I want to have slots that begin either with full hour or 30 min past full hour. Just like it works with hour view.

[image]

```
slotDuration: {minute: 5},
slotLabelInterval: {minute: 5},
slotMinutes: 5,
timezone: 'utc',
minTime: '00:00:00',
maxTime: '24:00:00',
views: {
    timelineDayView: {
        type: 'timeline',
        duration: { hour: 0.5 }, //{ minute: 30 }
        forceEventDuration: true,
        minTime: '00:00:00',
        maxTime: '24:00:00',
        buttonText: l_dayView,
        slotLabelFormat: [
            'MMMM', // top level of text
            'dddd DD.MM',
            'H:mm'
        ],
    },
```

How do I make the slots with fixed time?

Comment: I think that's just the way it works, for some reason once the `duration` is less than one hour. Maybe the fullCalendar devs assumed you'd want to zoom right into the current minute. Or maybe it's a bug. I don't know. You can report bugs here: https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: P.S. `I want to have slots that begin either with full hour or 30 min past full hour` doesn't actually make sense because you've purposely set your slotDuration to 5 minutes, so you'll never get half-hour _slots_. Do you mean you want the _view_ to start at exactly the full/half hour?

Comment: P.P.S. `slotMinutes` is not a valid setting. It was valid in version 1, but you clearly aren't using version 1.

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant that I want to view 30min divided into  5min slots. 
Thank you for your help